# How to generate float random numbers in Ada?

Tags: random, ada, protected

I have a program with tasks.
I want to generate two random numbers,

First: between 0.5 and 3.5

Second: between 4.5 and 6.5

I have to implement it in a protected unit:

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Numerics.Float_Random;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Numerics.Float_Random; 

procedure simulation is
.
.
.
    protected Helper is
            procedure generateFirstRandomNumber;
            procedure generateSecondRandomNumber;
    end Helper;
.
.
.
protected helper is
        procedure generateFirstRandomNumber is
        begin
        ...
        end generateFirstRandomNumber;

        procedure generateSecondRandomNumber is
        begin
        ...
        end generateSecondRandomNumber;

    end helper;
.
.
.
begin
.
.
.
end simulation;
```

I have two entry points where I have to pass those values.

So how can I implement that two random number generators in the protected unit?

Comment: How would you implement it outside the protected object? (And, technically, a PO can’t be a unit; units are compilable entities, a PO has to be inside a package (or, unusually, a subprogram - as in your example)). Once you’ve done that (and shown us by editing it into your question, please) we can talk about the PO part. One point - you’re going to want to return the random number to the caller, so the procedures will need `out` parameters.

Comment: I don't know what you wrote, cause my knowledge is very poor in Ada.

I want two procedure or function in the protected Helper, which generate two random numbers (the first one between 0.5 and 3.5 and the second between 4.5 and 6.5).
And I want to call it later.

Comment: Do you know how to use `Ada.Numerics.Float_Random.Random` to get a floating-point number in the range `0.0 .. 1.0`? Given such a result, do you know how to get a floating-point number in a different range?

Comment: subtype myRandom is float range 0.5..3.5 ?

Comment: If you want me to see a comment, tag me with, for example, "@KeithThompson". Click the "help" link next to the comment input box for details.  Let's try again. Do you know how to use `Ada.Numerics.Float_Random.Random` to get a floating-point number in the range `0.0 .. 1.0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sketch of part of a solution.

```ada
protected Helper is
   procedure Generate_First_Random_Number (Result : out Float);
   procedure Generate_Second_Random_Number (Result : out Float);
```

First, I hope I don't tread on your toes, but this is a more standard Ada style (Title_Case_With_Underscores).

Second, you need to get the results out somehow. You can't use a function, because functions aren't allowed to change the internal state of the PO, and (part of) that internal state is the random number generator.

Third, I'd have declared subtypes to represent the ranges you have to provide: `subtype Lower_Range is Float range 0.5 .. 3.5;`, for example.

```ada
private
   Gen : Ada.Numerics.Float_Random.Generator;
```

Internal variables have to be declared in the private part of the protected spec. And, as a general rule, it's better to use fully-qualified names, so it's obvious where the object's coming from (personally, I make an exception for `Ada.Text_IO`).

```ada
end Helper;

protected body Helper is
```

You have to use the word `body` here.

```ada
   procedure Generate_First_Random_Number (Result : out Float)
   is
      Rnd : constant Float := Ada.Numerics.Float_Random.Random (Gen);
```

`Rnd` is in the range `0.0 .. 1.0`,

```ada
   begin
      Result := 3.0 * Rnd + 0.5;
```

but you want a result in `0.5 .. 3.5`.

```ada
   end Generate_First_Random_Number;
```

... and similarly for the other procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears to be for your studies, I'll only point you in the right direction.  The [Ada Language Reference Manual](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-TOC.html) includes a detailed description of the Ada standard libraries.  These happen to include provisions for generating random floating point values with an equal distribution in a well-defined range.